# VSCode color customisation, Include regexp check in textMateRules

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to customize my VSCode theme using `textMateRules`. What I want to do is to change the color class names, but not all of them, only specific ones.

For example, in the project I'm working in, we have classes: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` ...

`A` and `B` are *"special"* classes and I would like to highlight them differently (let say in red). This is what I added for now in my `setting.json` file:

```json
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.type.class",
                
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000",
                }
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

But it is highlighting all the classes names (including `C`, `D` and all the others).

Is there a way to add more rules to the scope, like a regexp match?

Comment: use the Highlight extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) I used the [Highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight):

And I added this in my `setting.json`:

```json
{
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(A|B)": {
      "decorations": [
        {
          "color": "red"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
}
```