# vscode textmaterule to target react className string

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Found this awesome post on how to [dim semicolons in vscode](https://medium.com/@kachkaev/dimming-or-hiding-semicolons-in-vscode-a89cff48e2c3).

Thinking it could be useful for `javascriptreact` and `typescriptreact` files to do the same for the `className` string when working with class utilities like tailwind.

Anybody knows a way to tackle this?

---

It would be icing on the top bonus if the rule could be ignored when `j/tsx` element it focused.

Comment: find the TextMateScope  of the element you want to change and modify your settings, there are enough posts here on SO to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued to search SO after posting this (as suggested by @rioV8) and found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69415830/618099) answer to lead me near the goal.

Installed the [highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) and wrote this:

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(.*\\sclassName=\")(.*?)\"": [
      {},
      {
        "color": "grey"
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image: basic example]

[image: tailwind example]

Comment: had a couple of conflicting extensions that made it seem like it did not work at first, but it actually works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (no extension needed) solution would be

```json
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "string.quoted.double.tsx",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ffffff77"
        }
      }
   ]
```

The problem is that it targets too wide and not just scoped to `string.quoted.double.tsx` within the `className`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not the only one wanting a solution to the tailwind "noise" there is also an extension called "inline fold".

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold

https://youtube.com/shorts/4VUaoUAaMQg?feature=share